# Error handling for URLConnection

Tags: java, urlconnection, yahoo-finance

I have this method that downloads .csv files from yahoo finance and saves them locally.  It is accessed during a loop so it is downloading many files from a list.  However sometimes a symbol is entered incorrectly, no longer exists, or the connection times out.  How can I amend this method so that connection time outs are retried and incorrect symbols (meaning the url does not work) are just skipped over without ending the program?

```
public static void get_file(String symbol){

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    URLConnection  uCon = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    String finance_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol;
    String destination = "C:/"+symbol+"_table.csv";

    try {
        URL Url;
        byte[] buf;
        int ByteRead,ByteWritten=0;
        Url= new URL(finance_url);

        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination));

        uCon = Url.openConnection();
        is = uCon.getInputStream();         
        buf = new byte[size];

        while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
            ByteWritten += ByteRead;
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while downloading "+symbol);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            outStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your exeption will be caught in a try/catch block. What is the problem? What you program does in case of such problem, and what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not call the method again when an exception is thrown. You can narrow down the exception type to indicate when a retry should be initiated.

```
public static void get_file(String symbol){

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    URLConnection  uCon = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    String finance_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol;
    String destination = "C:/"+symbol+"_table.csv";

    try {
        URL Url;
        byte[] buf;
        int ByteRead,ByteWritten=0;
        Url= new URL(finance_url);

        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination));

        uCon = Url.openConnection();
        is = uCon.getInputStream();         
        buf = new byte[size];

        while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
            ByteWritten += ByteRead;
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
      getFile(symbol);
    }finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            outStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```